# OpenCV Script: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I'm trying to run the following script on OpenCV 3.4.1, Python 3.6.5, but I keep getting the error: `line 41, in <module> for i in range(defects.shape[0]): AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'`

I've tried changing `for i in range(defects.shape[0])`
to `for i in len(defects)` but that leads to the error: `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

I'm not experienced with Python or OpenCV, so any help will be appreciated!!

Here is the script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while( cap.isOpened() ) :
    ret,img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
    ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(blur,70,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    drawing = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)

    max_area=0

    for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
            cnt=contours[i]
            area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
            if(area>max_area):
                max_area=area
                ci=i
    cnt=contours[ci]
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
    moments = cv2.moments(cnt)
    if moments['m00']!=0:
                cx = int(moments['m10']/moments['m00']) # cx = M10/M00
                cy = int(moments['m01']/moments['m00']) # cy = M01/M00

    centr=(cx,cy)       
    cv2.circle(img,centr,5,[0,0,255],2)       
    cv2.drawContours(drawing,[cnt],0,(0,255,0),2) 
    cv2.drawContours(drawing,[hull],0,(0,0,255),2) 

    cnt = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints = False)

    if(1):
               defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)
               mind=0
               maxd=0
               for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
                    s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]
                    start = tuple(cnt[s][0])
                    end = tuple(cnt[e][0])
                    far = tuple(cnt[f][0])
                    dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt,centr,True)
                    cv2.line(img,start,end,[0,255,0],2)

                    cv2.circle(img,far,5,[0,0,255],-1)
               print(i)
               i=0
    cv2.imshow('output',drawing)
    cv2.imshow('input',img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k == 27:
        break
```

Comment: It means `cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)` returns `None`.

Comment: I would check if the contour (`cnt`) is None or empty, also, if the `hull` is None or empty and finally if both are not empty check also if defects is None...

Comment: @api55 how do I do that?

Comment: e.g. if cnt is None:  print ("no contour") ... and maybe do something like continue to the next value... same thing with hull and defects. You should also check if the variable is not none, if it is empty with shape or len